# Passing multiple data to and from android to webview

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, android-webview

I'm relatively new to Android and reusing a javascript code being used in IOS.

The code requires data being passed from Android. The tutorials I've seen so far pass a single toast message or a simple string.

How would I pass data from Android where I can access it from javascript similar to how `data.question` or `data.choices` is being accessed?

Also, the javascript below returns back the answer chosen by the user back to Android in the `passData()` function. Can someone please provide a sample code how I can accept and handle the return value to Android? I am using Kotlin.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function printData(data) {

                var questionLabel = document.getElementById("question")
                questionLabel.innerHTML = data.question
                var counterLabel = document.getElementById("counter")
                counterLabel.innerHTML = "Question " + data.activityCounter + " of " + data.numberOfActivities

                var im = document.createElement('img');
                if (data.graphicURI != null) {
                    im.src = data.graphicURI;
                    im.className = 'img-fluid img-rounded image-question';
                    document.getElementById('imageContainer').appendChild(im)
                }

                var i=0, doc = document, docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
                for (; i < data.choices.length ; i++){

                    var elem = doc.createElement('input');
                    elem.type = 'button';
                    elem.className = 'card mb-3 col-10 card-body';
                    elem.value = data.choices[i];
                    elem.tag = i;

                    elem.addEventListener("click", function() {
                                          passData(this.value)
                                          }, false);
                    docFrag.appendChild(elem);
                }

                document.getElementById("choicesContainer").appendChild(docFrag);

                if (((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) == false) {
                    document.getElementById("seeBottom").style.display = "block";
                }
            }

            function passData(data) {


                if (confirm("Are you sure you want to submit?")) {
                    console.log("yes");
                    window.webkit.messageHandlers.answer.postMessage(data);
                } else {
                    console.log("nO");
                }

            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First we need to create an interface between javascript code and client side android code,

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void sendValueToAndroid(int value) {

        // Do your operations on value here
        // For example:
        value = value * 500;
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Value is :" + value , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

**NOTE** : Don't forget to add `@JavascriptInterface` annotation above the function or else JS won't be able to recognise the function

Then we can bind this interface to the webview like,

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

Now the interface between android code and javascript is set. We can share data from javascript to android.

In order to access the function in javascript side call the function like this,

```
Android.sendValueToAndroid(5);
```

Here **Android** is the identifier to we use to denote JS that this is a function on the android side.

So in order to have other function like these add those to the WebAppInterface class and you can access that function on JS side like

```
Android.yourFunction();
```